# Creating custom objects with custom properties using generics

Tags: c#, generics, inheritance

I have two base classes: `City` and `Building`:

```
public class City
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public double Area { get; set; }
}

public class Building
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public double Area { get; set; }
    public int Stories { get; set; }
}
```

With two classes that inherit from `Building`, with their own `Id` property:

```
public class MyBuilding : Building
{
    public int MyId { get; set; }
}

public class HisBuilding : Building
{
    public int HisId { get; set; }
}
```

And two classes that inherit from `City`, with their own `Id` and `IEnumerable<Building>` properties:

```
public class MyCity : City
{
    public int MyId { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<MyBuilding> Buildings { get; set; }
}

public class HisCity : City
{
    public int HisId { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<HisBuilding> Buildings { get; set; }
}
```

Below is a method I've created that returns a `KeyValuePair<City, Building>` using generics:

```
public static KeyValuePair<TCity, IEnumerable<TBuilding>> GetData<TCity, TBuilding>()
    where TCity : City, new()
    where TBuilding : Building, new()
{
    TCity city = new TCity();
    IEnumerable<TBuilding> buildings = new List<TBuilding>();
    return new KeyValuePair<TCity, IEnumerable<TBuilding>>(city, buildings);
}
```

And in my `Main` method I've logic that instantiates a specific `City` object based on a user's input.

```
int input = -1;
string strInput = Console.ReadLine();
int.TryParse(strInput, out input);
string json = string.Empty;
switch (input)
{
    case 1:
        KeyValuePair<MyCity, IEnumerable<MyBuilding>> myCity
            = GetData<MyCity, MyBuilding>();
        MyCity my = myCity.Key;
        my.MyId = 1;
        my.Buildings = myCity.Value;
        json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(my, Formatting.Indented);
        break;

    default:
        KeyValuePair<HisCity, IEnumerable<HisBuilding>> hisCity
            = GetData<HisCity, HisBuilding>();
        HisCity his = hisCity.Key;
        his.HisId = 2;
        his.Buildings = hisCity.Value;
        json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(his, Formatting.Indented);
        break;
}
Console.WriteLine(json);
Console.ReadLine();
```

The above generic method is just something I cobbled together in the last half hour, but I'm wondering if there is a more efficient way of creating these custom objects of mine, especially when each `City` has its own, different `IEnumerable<Building>` property.

**EDIT**

Here is the code I have for building the `IEnumerable` inside my `GetData` method:

```
public static IEnumerable<TBuilding> GetBuildingData<TBuilding>() 
    where TBuilding : Building, new()
{
    DataTable table;
    string myConnectionString = @"Data Source=(LocalDb)\MSSQLLocalDb;Initial Catalog=Test;Integrated Security=True;";
    List<TBuilding> buildings = new List<TBuilding>();
    using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(myConnectionString))
    {
        using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("[dbo].[GetListData]", connection) { CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure })
        {
            connection.Open();
            using (SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(command))
            {
                table = new DataTable();
                adapter.Fill(table);
            }
            connection.Close();
        }
    }
    foreach (DataRow row in table.Rows)
    {
        TBuilding building = new TBuilding();
        building.Area = Convert.ToDouble(row["Area"]);
        building.Name = row["Name"].ToString();
        building.Stories = Convert.ToInt32(row["Stories"]);
        buildings.Add(building);
    }
    return buildings;
}
```

Comment: Could you provide a working example of how you would use such functionality? Atm you just have 2 objects with empty lists. What is the point of this?

Comment: Best practices you should make a constructor for types that have properties of ienumerable or collection types and fill them in with a default value and not return null.  For IEnumerable just use Enumerable.Empty https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.empty?view=netframework-4.8

Comment: @dfhwze I work with multiple clients and send them all notifications periodically. The notifications contain some of the same data, but `Id` properties are client-specific, so I'm working to build out the base objects generically, then add the custom ids later on.

Comment: Your method creates an empty list. How would you fill this list? I find this part crucial to review your code :)

Comment: @dfhwze I edited my question to include the code I'm using to build that list.

Comment: Thanks for the edit. Is using an ORM an option for you or do you require custom mapping and SqlDataAdapter /DataTable interop?

Comment: I've never used ORM before nor have much of an idea of what it is.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I will focus on..

> Creating custom objects with custom properties using generics

Which you do in this method..

> ```
> public static KeyValuePair<TCity, IEnumerable<TBuilding>> GetData<TCity, TBuilding>()
>     where TCity : City, new()
>     where TBuilding : Building, new()
> {
>     TCity city = new TCity();
>     IEnumerable<TBuilding> buildings = new List<TBuilding>();
>     return new KeyValuePair<TCity, IEnumerable<TBuilding>>(city, buildings);
> }
> ```

- A `KeyValuePair` is archaic, you can use a `ValueTuple` nowadays
- `TBuilding` does not require the `new()` constraint in this method
- The choice for `IEnumerable` over `IList` is questionable, since you retrieve the items later on and have no way of adding them to an `IEnumerable`. So why create the `IEnumerable` in this method?
- The name should reflect what you are doing. `CreateCity` seems more appropriate.

I would refactor this method..

```
public static (TCity city, IList<TBuilding> buildings) CreateCity<TCity, TBuilding>()
    where TCity : City, new()
    where TBuilding : Building
{
    var city = new TCity();
    var buildings = new List<TBuilding>();
    return (city, buildings);
}
```

EDIT:

Thinking about the refactored method. This doesn't even need to be a method anymore. It doesn't do anything but create objects for the types you specify.

What I would really do is throw out this ancient way of ORM, and use an existing API (EF, NHibernate, Dapper).

Comment: I'm afraid we might here at some point _this code is simplified, in my real code I actually do this and that_ :-\

Comment: When I refactor my method using the code you've posted, by replacing the `KeyValuePair<TCity, IEnumerable<TBuilding>>` with `(TCity city, IList<TBuilding> buildings` I just end up with a bunch of errors. Could this be because I'm using Visual Studio 2015?

Comment: ValueTuple is supported since https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/mazhou/2017/05/26/c-7-series-part-1-value-tuples/. You could keep using KeyValuePair instead, or use a regular Tuple.

Comment: ...about the ancient tools... it looks like you should add another one to this list and suggest using VS2019 :-P

Answer (score 3):

> ```
> public class MyBuilding : Building
> {
>     public int MyId { get; set; }
> }
>
> public class HisBuilding : Building
> {
>     public int HisId { get; set; }
> }
> ```

Why do you have the id as properties of the subclasses, it's a candidate for a base class member:

```
public class Building
{
  public int Id { get; set; }
```

If the subclasses must have specialized names for their `Id` property, then provide that as:

```
public class MyBuilding : Building
{
    public int MyId { get { return Id; } set { Id = value; } }
}
```

but that is a rather odd concept that you should avoid if possible.

The same holds for `Cities`.

---

```
public class MyCity : City
{
    public int MyId { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<MyBuilding> Buildings { get; set; }
}
```

Normally you would have a materialized data set for buildings instead of an `IEnumerable<T>` - unless you're creating the instances lazily/dynamically. You could maybe consider using a `IReadonlyList<T>` as type, if you don't want it to be modifiable or else just a `IList<T>`

---

> ```
> public static KeyValuePair<TCity, IEnumerable<TBuilding>> GetData<TCity, TBuilding>()
>     where TCity : City, new()
>     where TBuilding : Building, new()
> {
>     TCity city = new TCity();
>     IEnumerable<TBuilding> buildings = new List<TBuilding>();
>     return new KeyValuePair<TCity, IEnumerable<TBuilding>>(city, buildings);
> }
> ```

If you changed the City base class to a generic like:

```
public class City<TBuilding> where TBuilding: Building
{
  public IList<TBuilding> Buildings { get; set; }
}
```

and dropped the buildings on the specialized cities, then you could return just the city from `GetData`, because you can initialize the `Buildings` property inside `GetData`, which I would rename to `CreateCity()`

```
public static TCity CreateCity<TCity, TBuilding>()
where TCity : City<TBuilding>, new()
where TBuilding : Building, new()
{
  TCity city = new TCity();
  city.Buildings = new List<TBuilding>();
  return city;
}
```

---

Ideally you could have a common baseclass for `City` and `Building`, because they share some significant properties like `Id`, `Area` and `Name`:

```
public abstract class AreaObject
{
  public int Id { get; set; }
  public string Name { get; set; }
  public double Area { get; set; }
}
```

A complete refactoring of your data model could then be:

```
public abstract class AreaObject
{
  public int Id { get; set; }
  public string Name { get; set; }
  public double Area { get; set; }
}

// For convenience a city base class without the generic type parameter:
public abstract class City : AreaObject
{
  public abstract IEnumerable<Building> GetBuildings();
}

public class City<TBuilding> : City where TBuilding : Building
{
  public IList<TBuilding> Buildings { get; set; }

  public override IEnumerable<Building> GetBuildings()
  {
    return Buildings;
  }
}

public class Building : AreaObject
{
  public int Stories { get; set; }
}

public class MyBuilding : Building
{
  public int MyId { get { return Id; } set { Id = value; } }
}

public class HisBuilding : Building
{
  public int HisId { get { return Id; } set { Id = value; } }
}

public class MyCity : City<MyBuilding>
{
  public int MyId { get { return Id; } set { Id = value; } }
}

public class HisCity : City<HisBuilding>
{
  public int HisId { get { return Id; } set { Id = value; } }
}
```

It's a little odd to have two different sub cities having specialized buildings instead of just `Building`s, but you may have reasons for that? (What if `MyCity` buys a building from `HisCity` can it then change from `His` to `My`?)

---

> Here is the code I have for building the `IEnumerable` inside my
>   `GetData` method:
>
> `public static IEnumerable<TBuilding> GetBuildingData<TBuilding>()...`

If that is going to be used inside `GetData()` shouldn't it then take a city id as argument in order to minimize the query? If so you can change the `GetData` to:

```
public static TCity CreateCity<TCity, TBuilding>(int id)
where TCity : City<TBuilding>, new()
where TBuilding : Building, new()
{
  TCity city = new TCity();
  city.Buildings = GetBuildingData<TBuilding>(id);
  city.Id = id;
  return city;
}
```

And you'll then have to modify your database query to only return the buildings for that city:

```
public static IList<TBuilding> GetBuildingData<TBuilding>(int cityId)
where TBuilding : Building, new() {...}
```

---

All in all this could simplify your use case to:

```
  int cityId = -1;
  string strInput = Console.ReadLine();
  int.TryParse(strInput, out cityId);
  if (cityId > 0)
  {
    City city = null;

    switch (cityId)
    {
      case 1:
        city = CreateCity<MyCity, MyBuilding>(cityId);
        break;
      case 2:
        city = CreateCity<HisCity, HisBuilding>(cityId);
        break;
      default:
        throw new InvalidOperationException("Invalid Id");
    }

    string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(city, Formatting.Indented);
    Console.WriteLine(json);
    Console.ReadLine();
  }
```

---

**Update**

As mentioned a couple of times in the above, the data model and class structure for especially `City` is rather unusual. A more conventional structure could be something like:

```
public abstract class AreaObject
{
  public int Id { get; set; }
  public string Name { get; set; }
  public double Area { get; set; }
}

public abstract class City : AreaObject
{
  public IList<Building> Buildings { get; set; }
}

public class MyCity : City
{
  // Uncomment if you really need this: public IList<MyBuilding> MyBuildings => Buildings.Where(b => b is MyBuilding).Cast<MyBuilding>().ToList();
}

public class HisCity : City
{
  // Uncomment if you really need this: public IList<HisBuilding> HisBuildings => Buildings.Where(b => b is HisBuilding).Cast<HisBuilding>().ToList();
}

public class Building : AreaObject
{
  public int Stories { get; set; }
}

public class MyBuilding : Building
{
}

public class HisBuilding : Building
{
}
```

As shown, `City` owns the `Buildings` property. The original concept of having specialized building properties per city sub class, doesn't make much sense in real life, because what defines a building: its relation to a city or its materials, functionality etc.? Can't two cities have a copy of the same building? And a `MyCity` should be able to Buy a building from `HisCity` etc. And a city should be able to own different types of building.

The factory method could then be simplified to this:

```
  public static TCity CreateCity<TCity>(int id)
    where TCity : City, new()
  {
    TCity city = new TCity();
    city.Buildings = GetBuildingData(id);
    city.Id = id;
    return city;
  }

  public static IList<Building> GetBuildingData(int cityId)
  {
    // The sql stuff...
  }
```

And the use case to:

```
  public static void Run()
  {
    int cityId = -1;
    string strInput = Console.ReadLine();
    int.TryParse(strInput, out cityId);
    if (cityId > 0)
    {
      City city = null;

      switch (cityId)
      {
        case 1:
          city = CreateCity<MyCity>(cityId);
          break;
        case 2:
          city = CreateCity<HisCity>(cityId);
          break;
        default:
          throw new InvalidOperationException("Invalid Id");
      }

      string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(city, Formatting.Indented);
      Console.WriteLine(json);
      Console.ReadLine();
    }
  }
```

Comment: Why both an `abstract` `City` class and a normal `City` class?

Comment: @Delfino: In order to make the polymorphism work properly, so you'll be able to write: `City city = new MyCity();`. Your need to have two different sub cities with specialized `Building` properties is highly unusual, and breaks the normal concept of inheritance and polymorphism. There is no good solution to that IMO. I'll update my answer with a more conventional data model in a moment.